# Idiomatic approach to captioned subfigures and tables with the 2017 acmart class?

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats, acm, acmart

In late 2016, the ACM published its [2017 ACM Master Article Template](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template). This document class breaks a lot of LaTeX code one might have written using earlier ACM document classes, specifically the `sig-alternate` class.

Specifically, I've been having trouble captioning tables, and using subfigures (captioned or otherwise), with the new class. The [user's guide](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart.pdf) says nothing about this, specifically not in Section 2.5, dealing with figures and tables.

Instead of asking about something specific which did not work for me, what I'd like to know is the common, idiomatic if you will, approach to this issue:

- Which combination(s) of packages to use with the class (`subfigure`, `subcaption`, `subfig`, `floatrow` etc.)?
- Is there some special initialization, `\patchcmd`ing or other voodoo incantation I should include in my preamble?
- Are there specific figure/subfigure layouts I should avoid, or be careful about? Ditto w.r.t. captioning.

Comment: you'd probably be more likely to get an answer if you did provide an example and say what error you got, many of us will not have used the class but it's usually possible to debug an example, if provided.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The thing is, I've already tried a dozen different combinations of things which haven't worked out, but I didn't do it systematically so I can't recount any of it. But - you know what? Challenge accepted. I'll make this more concrete (within a day or two).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Working on it right now. First thing I found - my captioning was being thwarted because I had defined a command named `\tblname`. Big mistake... onwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to expand Boris’ answer, here's how you can (and should) do with `subcaption`. Instead of `\autoref` I believe it's better to use `\cref` from `\cleveref`.

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% You don't need this block of lines in your article - I do
% need, them since I use placeholders instead of actual graphics
\usepackage{tcolorbox} % for graphics placeholders
\newcommand{\graphicsplaceholder}[2]{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[valign=center,width=#1,height=#2,arc=0.5mm,auto outer arc]%
    \centering \sf missing graphic%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}

\begin{document}

\title{Tables, figures and subfigures \texorpdfstring{\\}{}
   with the new ACM 2017 article template}
\author{Nobody in particular}
\affiliation{\institution{University of Life}}
\email{no.body@life.edu}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{abstract}

\section{Figures}

Let's start with a simple figure, single-column, no subfigures --- using a
\texttt{figure} environment. That will be \cref{figure-with-no-subfigs}.

\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \centering
  % What you would typically have here is something like:
  % \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{some-file.pdf}
  % but for this example, let's go with a placeholder instead:
  \graphicsplaceholder{8cm}{1cm}
  \caption{This is a figure with no subfigures}
  \label{figure-with-no-subfigs}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Figures with subfigures}

Let's add a figure with two subfigures; the subfigures will be added with
\verb|\subcaptionbox{caption goes here}|, so they should also be captioned. 
That will be \cref{first-figure-with-subfigures}.

\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Some subfigure\label{first-subfig}}{%
    % What you would typically have here is something like:
    % \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{some-file.pdf}
    % but for this example, let's go with a placeholder instead:
    \graphicsplaceholder{4cm}{1cm}%
  }
  \subcaptionbox{Another subfigure\label{second-subfig}}{%
    \graphicsplaceholder{4cm}{1cm}%
  }
  \caption{A caption for the single-column figure with two subfigures}
  \label{first-figure-with-subfigures}
\end{figure}

Let's conclude this section by repeating the same figure, but now as a 
two-column figure, i.e. using the \verb|{figure*}| environment. That will 
be \cref{a-two-column-figure}, with \cref{first-subfig} and \cref{second-subfig}.

\begin{figure*}[htpb]
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Yet another caption\label{third-subfig}}{%
    \graphicsplaceholder{8cm}{1cm}%
  }
  \subcaptionbox{This is getting old\label{fourth-subfig}}{%
    \graphicsplaceholder{8cm}{1cm}%
  }
  \caption{A caption for the two-column figure (also with two subfigures)}
  \label{a-two-column-figure}
\end{figure*}

\section{Tables}

Let's add a \texttt{table} environment, with a caption near the end of it
(after the \texttt{tabular} environment). That will be \cref{first-table}.

\begin{table}[thpb]
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is a caption for a \texttt{table} float, with a 
  \texttt{tabular} environment inside it}
\label{first-table}
\end{table}

And we're all done, except for one last thing...:

\paragraph{Warning} Don't ever define a \verb|\tblname| command. This was 
possible with older ACM document class (e.g. \texttt{sig-alternate} v2.8), 
but now it will trigger errors when you try to caption your floats.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (1) About `autoref` vs `\cref` - I used `\autoref` since `acmart` already uses `hyperref`; with that in mind, do you still believe `\cref` should be preferred? (2) Are you suggesting that `subcaption` should be preferred over `subfig` always, or just for `acmart` documents? (3) Your images look like everything is typeset in heavier weight somehow, plus I edited a bit, so perhaps this should be regenerated.

Comment: @einpoklum In general, `subcaption` is to be preferred over `subfig`. I see no “heavier” typesetting. Your first edit removed some comments from the code; the second one adds text that I find useless.

Comment: @egreg Shouldn't the example in the first section reference `third-subfig` and `fourth-subfig`?

Comment: @MichaelMior Possibly so, I believe I used some random references.

Comment: @egreg It seems like you were intending to refer to specific subfigures and you mistakenly picked the wrong ones. Not worth redoing the images for though I suppose :)

Answer (score 2):

Section 2.12 of the user guide recommends `subcaption` package "for complex figures with several subplots or subfigures that require separate subcaptioning."

Comment: You're right. But I wasn't using `subcaption` before. Do you think there's a good reason to use that over `subfig`? (see my answer below)

Comment: @einpoklum For instance, `subcaption` is compatible with `hyperref`, whereas `subfig` isn't completely so.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the following works. Feedback in comments is appreciated regarding the choice of packages or anything else.

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% You don't need this block of lines in your article - I do
% need them, since I use placeholders instead of actual graphics
\usepackage{tcolorbox} % for graphics placeholders
\newcommand{\graphicsplaceholder}[2]{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[valign=center,width=#1,height=#2,arc=0.5mm,auto outer arc]%
    \centering%
     \sf missing graphic%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\title{Tables, figures and subfigures \\ with the new ACM 2017 article template}

\author{Nobody in particular}
\affiliation{ \institution{University of Life} }
\email{no.body@life.edu}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{abstract}

\section{Figures}

Let's start with a simple figure, single-column, no subfigures --- using a 
\texttt{figure} environment. That will be \autoref{figure-with-no-subfigs}.

\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \centering
  % What you would typically have here is something like:
  % \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{some-file.pdf}
  % but for this example, let's go with a placeholder instead:
  \graphicsplaceholder{8cm}{1cm}
  \caption{This is a figure with no subfigures}
  \label{figure-with-no-subfigs}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Figures with subfigures}

Le'ts add a figure with two subfigures; the subfigures will be added using 
\verb|\subfloat[caption goes here]|, so they should also be captioned. 
That will be \autoref{first-figure-with-subfigures}.

\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \centering
  \subfloat[Some subfigure]{
    \graphicsplaceholder{4cm}{1cm}
    \label{first-subfig}
  }
  \subfloat[Another subfigure]{
    \graphicsplaceholder{4cm}{1cm}
    \label{second-subfig}
  }
  \caption{A caption for the single-column figure with two subfigures}
  \label{first-figure-with-subfigures}
\end{figure}

Let's conclude this section by repeating the same figure, but now as a two-column
figure, i.e. using the \verb|{figure*}| environment. That will be
\autoref{a-two-column-figure}.

\begin{figure*}[htpb]
  \centering
  \subfloat[Yet another caption]{
    \graphicsplaceholder{8cm}{1cm}
    \label{third-subfig}
  }
  \subfloat[This is getting old]{
    \graphicsplaceholder{8cm}{1cm}
    \label{fourth-subfig}
  }
  \caption{A caption for the two-column figure (also with two subfigures)}
  \label{a-two-column-figure}
\end{figure*}

\section{Tables}

Let's add a \texttt{table} environment, with a caption near the end of it (after
 the \texttt{tabular} environment). That will be \autoref{first-table}.

\begin{table}[thpb]
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is a caption for a \texttt{table} float, with a \texttt{tabular} 
environment inside it}
\label{first-table}
\end{table}

And we're all done, except for one last thing...:

\paragraph{Warning} Don't ever define a \verb|\tblname| command. This was 
possible with older ACM document class (e.g. \texttt{sig-alternate} v2.8), 
but now it will trigger errors when you try to caption your floats.

\end{document}
```

And when I compile this with TeXLive 2015.20160320-1 (the distribution-provided version on Linux Mint 18.1), I get two pages:

[image: Page 1 of 2 of the output]
[image: Page 2 of 2 of the output]

Notes:

- The reason I don't use `subcaption` is that, well, this is close to what I was using with older ACM classes, and I've opted for minimum changes to get things working (but feel free to criticize).
- I don't know why I get the block starting with "ACM Reference Format". Do they do that on purpose? It's really hard on the eyes and annoying.
- I'm not sure how to balance the columns now (but this example is not about column balancing).
- There's no page numbering - probably since these things go inside proceedings PDF's which have their running numbers over many articles.
- I'm not quite sure why the `figure*` environment clears the page. Shouldn't the text just fill up the two columns before it, with the figure coming afterwards? Hmm.

Comment: `subfigure` has been obsolete for at least 15 years.

Comment: @egreg: Hmm. I remembered some packages are obsolete, but I somehow manage to get them confused. Fixed.

Comment: have you figured out how to place `figure*` on the same page where it was declared? In your example, it is a bit difficult, since it is the first page. But I'm trying to have a wide figure on top of second page (written in text that belongs to 2nd page), but it keeps getting placed on 3rd one, despite `htbp` modifier